# Show differences at row level between columns of 2 dataframes Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have 2 dataframes containing names and some demographic information, the dataframes are not identical due to monthly changes.

I'd like to create another df to show just the names of people where there are changes in either their COUNTRY or JOBCODE or MANAGERNAME columns, and also show what kind of changes these are.

Have tried the following code so far and am able to detect changes in the country column in the 2 dataframes for the common rows.

But am not so sure how to capture the movement in the MOVEMENT columns. Appreciate any form of help.

```
#Merge first
dfmerge = pd.merge(df1, df2, how ='inner', on ='EMAIL')

#create function to get COUNTRY_CHANGE column
def change_in(dfmerge):
    if dfmerge['COUNTRY_x'] != dfmerge['COUNTRY_y']:
        return 'YES'
    else:
        return 'NO'
dfmerge['COUNTRYCHANGE'] = dfmerge.apply(change_in, axis = 1)
```

Dataframe 1

```
NAME           EMAIL                COUNTRY      JOBCODE      MANAGERNAME
Jason Kelly    jasonkelly@123.com   USA          1221         Jon Gilman  
Jon Gilman     jongilman@123.com    CANADA       1222         Cindy Lee 
Jessica Lang   jessicalang@123.com  AUSTRALIA    1221         Esther Donato
Bob Wilder     bobwilder@123.com    ROMANIA      1355         Mike Lens 
Samir Bala     samirbala@123.com    CANADA       1221         Ricky Easton
```

Dataframe 2

```
NAME           EMAIL                COUNTRY      JOBCODE      MANAGERNAME
Jason Kelly    jasonkelly@123.com   VIETNAM      1221         Jon Gilman  
Jon Gilman     jongilman@123.com    CANADA       4464         Sheldon Tracey 
Jessica Lang   jessicalang@123.com  AUSTRALIA    2224         Esther Donato
Bob Wilder     bobwilder@123.com    ROMANIA      1355         Emilia Tanner
```

Desired Output

```
EMAIL                COUNTRY_CHANGE COUNTRY_MOVEMENT     JOBCODE_CHANGE JOBCODE_MOVEMENT  MGR_CHANGE MGR_MOVEMENT
jasonkelly@123.com   YES            FROM USA TO VIETNAM  NO             NO                NO         NO
jongilman@123.com    NO             NO                   YES            FROM 1222 to 4464 YES        FROM Cindy Lee to Sheldon Tracey 
jessicalang@123.com  NO             NO                   YES            FROM 1221 to 2224 NO         NO
bobwilder@123.com    NO             NO                   NO             NO                YES        FROM Mike Lens to Emilia Tanner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not direct feature in pandas that can help but we may leverage merge function as follows. We are merging dataframes and providing suffix to merged columns and then reporting their differences via this code.

```
# Assuming df1 and df2 are input data frames in your example.
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['name', 'email'], suffixes=['past', 'present'])

dfans = pd.DataFrame() # this is the final output data frame
for column in df1.columns:
    if not (column + 'present' in df3.columns or column + 'past' in df3.columns):
        # Here we handle those columns which will not be merged like name and email.
        dfans.loc[:, column] = df1.loc[:, column]  # filling name and email as it is
    else:
        # string manipulation to name columns correctly in output
        newColumn1 = '{}_CHANGE'.format(column)
        newColumn2 = '{}_MOVEMENT'.format(column)
        past, present = "{}past".format(column), "{}present".format(column)
        
        # creating the output based on input
        dfans.loc[:, newColumn1] = (df3[past] == df3[present]).map(lambda x: "YES" if x != 1 else "NO")
        dfans.loc[:, newColumn2] = ["FROM {} TO {}".format(x, y) if x != y else "NO" for x, y in
                                    zip(df3[past], df3[present])]
```